# What is the maximum size we can specify for maxItemsInObjectGraph of dataContractSerializer in web.config?

Tags: wcf, web-config, datacontractserializer

What is the maximum size we can specify for maxItemsInObjectGraph of dataContractSerializer in web.config ?

Currently we have it as 22020096.And because of this sometimes the data that comes from our upstream is not getting processed successfully.After we increased it to 52020096,it works fine.

But I would like to know what is the limit for maxItemsInObjectGraph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported type (formatted as a string in the web.config) is an integer (as that is the type the value is mapped to), and the default value is [`int.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) (which is 2,147,483,647). This is stated on the MSDN documentation page for [`MaxItemsInObjectGraph`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx). It can't go any higher.

Comment: Can I safely change it to  2,147,483,647 from 22020096? Do I need to take care of anything while doing this ?